# Homology with real coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, modules, homological-algebra

I am looking for a proof as elementary as possible of the fact that $H_k(X,\mathbb{Z})\bigotimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ injects into $H_k(X,\mathbb{R})$, where $H_k$ denotes the homology group of a topological space (in my case, a compact manifold even). I know that this is a trivial consequence of the universal coefficient theorem for homology (i.e. 3A.3 in Hatcher), but I am wondering if there is a simpler proof for this specific case.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use the universal coefficient, and the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ being torsion free implies that it is flat as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I don't completely understand what you mean by 'using the universal coefficient'. $\mathbb{R}$ is flat, so we get an injection from $H_k(X, \mathbb{Z}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$ into $H_k(X, \mathbb{R}) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \mathbb{R}$, right?

Comment: The first case discussed, for instance, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem. I would suggest maybe following Hatcher's book for a construction of the first map in the sequence.